# Multiprocessing the Python module 'emcee', but not all available cores on the machine are being used

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, emcee

I am parallelizing emcee using multiprocessing module as stated in the emcee document. However, htop shows that the program keeps using a limited number of cores (26-27). The computer I am running my code on has 80 available cores and I would like to make use of all of them to speed up the code.

Can someone please help me with this? I did not find any solution in the document.

Comment: Most operating systems define physical and logical processor groups. Windows in particular has no more than 64 logical processors per group, and ["By default, an application is constrained to a single group"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processor-groups). I would assume Linux also may have similar limitations. You may double check what `multiprocessing.cpu_count` reports. There are also often process, memory, and file handle limits by default from the shell (something like `ulimit`). Finally make sure your're not just IO limited by disk speed...

Comment: @ Aaron Thank you. I checked `multiprocessing.cpu_count` and it gives me 80. I am also not limited. When I use multiprocessing module in other programs I see with htop that all 80 cores are being used. But with 'emcee' this limitation still exists which is really slowing down my code ...

Comment: In that case it may be a limitation of the library or the algorithm used by the library.

Comment: @ Aaron Thank you very much for your insight. I just found out that emcee uses a number of cores equal to half the number of walkers, that's why not all cores are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone runs into the same issue, I just found out that `emcee` will use a number of cores equal to half the number of walkers. In my case I had 50 walkers and hence, 25 CPU cores were being used.